# Python file can't find local package

Tags: python, bash, package, pycharm, init

When I run `backup.py`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'router_move'`

`backup.py`

```py
import socket
from router_move.backup_mikrotik import backup_mikrotik
from router_move.backup_eltex import backup_eltex
from router_move.backup_cisco import backup_cisco


def run_backup(directory: str) -> None:
    try:
        backup_mikrotik(directory)
        backup_eltex(directory)
        backup_cisco(directory)
    except socket.gaierror:
        print('unknown ip')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_backup('/Users/egorgulido/Desktop')
```

But if i run this file with PyCharm, it does work as it need to does

Tree
router_move/
├── `__init__.py`
├── `app.py`
├── `backup.py`
├── `backup_cisco.py`
├── `backup_eltex.py`
├── `backup_mikrotik.py`
├── `models.py`
└── `views.py`

I don't have any clue.
May be, PyCharm does something when it runs the file

I think here is a stupid mistake

Comment: Show us exactly how you are running the code.

Comment: `python backup.py`

Comment: With `backup.py` as main script the `router_move.` part must be removed from the imports.

Comment: `from router_move.backup_mikrotik import backup_mikrotik` This import expects a subdirectory named `router_move`.  But when you run `python backup.py`, you are _already_ in that subdirectory.

Comment: If I run this without `router_move`, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'backup_mikrotik' from partially initialized module 'backup_mikrotik' (most likely due to a circular import)`
I think, because of using `backup.py` in my `views.py`

Comment: @JohnGordon
If i try to run this with `router_move` by PyCharm it'll work

Comment: Pycharm may be modifying your Python search path. Whatever directory contains `router_move` must be in the value of `sys.path` in order for the import mechanism to find the package `router_move`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```py
from .backup_mikrotik import backup_mikrotik
from .backup_eltex import backup_eltex
from .backup_cisco import backup_cisco
```